# Find index of the last occurence for maximal value in pd.DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I need to find `argmax` index in pd.DataFrame. I want exacly the same result, as `pandas.DataFrame.idxmax` does, but this function returns index of **first** occurrence of maximum over requested axis. I want find index of **last** occurrence of maximum. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Run `df[::-1].idxmax()`

The trick is to process rows in **reversed** order.

Comment: When I wrote this answer I didn't know that there is another answer (indeed, just the same).